# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (68): y

Tags: r

Please can someone help me here. I am getting an below error: 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (68): y

Dataset:
Name    Cases
A        100
B         50
C         20..... total rows 58+10(blank rows)= 68

```
    library(tidyverse)

`# Create dataset`
    data <-dataset
    value <- dataset$Cases
 `# Set a number of 'empty bar'`
    empty_bar <- 10

`# Add lines to the initial dataset`
    to_add <- matrix(NA, empty_bar, ncol(data))
    colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
    data <- rbind(data, to_add)
    data$id <- seq(1, nrow(data))

`# Get the name and the y position of each label`
    label_data <- data
    number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
    angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     
`# I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)`
    label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
    label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

`# Make the plot`
    pChart <- ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value)) +       
`# Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar`
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=alpha("green", 0.3)) + ylim(-100,120) +
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
    ) +
    coord_polar(start = 0) + 
    geom_text(data=label_data, 
            aes(x=id, y=value, label=Name,
            hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, 
            angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) 
    pChart
```

Comment: Is it possible, that there is no column `value` in your dataset `data`?

Comment: True, but I passed the column "Dataset$Cases" values into "value", which is now vectorized.

Comment: Without see an example of your data, it is nearly impossible to figure out where the error is.  It is possible the error is in the `geom_text()` line.  Trying to isolate which line in the ggplot definition is causing the problem.  Then edit and update the question with more information.

Comment: Thanks all, I figured, one of the column was not returning right data. It works now.